# Grease Pencil object opacity as one image, not individual layers

Tags: modifiers, grease-pencil, blend-modes

Currently when I turn down the opacity of my grease pencil object with the opacity modifier, places where strokes overlap become darker. I want the object's opacity to behave more like a single image. Any ways I can accomplish this?
[image]

Comment: I think it's a blender limitation, but it might be worth filling a bug report? I mean, the default behaviour should definitely be what you're expecting here

Comment: merge all grease pencil layers

Answer (score 0):

In the "visual effect properties" tab, choose the "colorize" effect, put it on transparency mode. This will give the desired effect.
[image]

Comment: didn't even know there was a minimum length. Was in a bit of a hurry. It should be better now.